# How to animate UITableView offscreen like the Facebook app checkins view

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

In the facebook app for iOS, in the nearby view there is a UITableView with a map at the top, when the user pulls down on the table, the table animates offscreen downwards and the map takes up the whole screen. Using an upwards gesture, the table view is brought back into view.
[image: facebook app]
<sub>(source: [elandroidelibre.com](https://www.elandroidelibre.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DisplayMedia-289x600.png))</sub>

My question is, how is this achievable in an elegant way. I played around with ContentOffset and ContentInset, but nothing I have tried has really worked. Any ides or suggestions? Thanks for you help.

Comment: This is not the view you get from "Check Ins", it's the view from selecting "Nearby" on the side menu.  They look similar but don't behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the backgroundView of UITableView contains a MKMapView, so as you swipe the table view cells downward more of the backgroundView is revealed.  In other words, the UIScrollView that contains the table view cells is scrolling up and down which reveals the backgroundView.  It also looks like the mapView center is being changed to keep the current location in the center of the visible background area.

Comment: I can get that part to work, but it's the animation where if you pull the whole table view down and let go, it is animated offscreen.

Comment: What is animated off screen?  I don't see that happening.

Comment: If you pull from the top of the table down and take your finger off when it is at the bottom, the table animates down, and the map pulls out and goes fullscreen

Comment: If you swipe the menu to the side and tap Nearby.

Comment: Ah found it.  But you can't do that gesture if you got to the list from the "Check In" button on the Newsfeed, this only works if you go to the side menu and select Nearby.